# Which classifier can be used for rail line detection using C++ and OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

It is may be a very simple question. I am searching for a classifier which can be trained using C++ and OpenCV libraries for rail line detection.
Can anybody give a brief idea.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you thought of Haar classifiers? Yes the same ones used to detect faces. You can train your own Haar classifier using different images of rail lines having various orientations. [THIS LINK](https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/) would help you get started.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have been using Haar cascade classifier since last 2 months. May be I am wrong, but from my experience, Haar feature is not suitable for detecting rail line. For a rigid object which has a lot of variation on pixel value, Haar classifier can be a right choice. In a rail line, it is not getting enough pixel variation, where as much as possible features pattern can be used. Are there any other classifier, which can be used for rail line detection. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try HOG (Hitogram of gradients) classifier for a change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Railway lines can be easier to detect with HOG or SIFT features, given the types of features that they contain. However, I would recommend YOLO 9000. If it already knows how to detect railway tracks, you are in luck. Otherwise, it can be trained with a collection of images.